# How can I hide the errors session messages of my module?

Tags: magento2, error, session

In **Magento 2**, it shows an error which is really annoying for customers. How can we hide or remove showing those errors in the page?

Currently, the application is in the **production mode**. But still, the following error is shown.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can try this reference to remove that  message : https://www.interactiv4.com/blog-es-en/automatically-hide-messages-in-magento-2/?lang=enthat

Comment: These are error message coming from your tracking module. Please check the controller of your module and remove the error messages from there.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, this is basic magento tracking selected and can you please tell where I can get the controller for magento tracking?

Comment: Do you want to remove all error messages in magento for every pages? Or for these 2 pages?

Comment: You must find the controll who add this messages error and remove it

Comment: How to find this controller?

Answer (score 0):

Go to : `app/code/{Vendor}/{Yourmodulename}/Controller/.../... .php` Then you w'ill fine `addError` in some lines like this :

> $this->messageManager->addError(__('An error occurred while....'));

Replace them with :

```
$this->logger->info('An error occurred while....');
```

**Important:** If you haven't yet this piece of code `$this->logger` or sometimes like this : `$this->_logger` please inject it in the contructor like this:

```
protected $logger;
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    ...
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Now the errors will be displayed in `var/log` instead in frontend

Comment: How can I find the *Yourmodulename* in Magento 2 for making this change?

Comment: Your tracking module

Comment: I have fixed this for the tracking module. But how to find thr controller for the second image? Its actually the search result page.

Comment: `module-catalog-search` module but you should rewrite it (don't update it directly) from `vendor/magento/Module-catalog-search`